# strtok is causing a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, string, strtok

I have to get the third word in a string and wanted to use **strtok**. Now, the first **printf** works but after that I get a Seg Fault. So `tokenizedString = strtok(NULL, " ");` must be causing the issue, right?

Just for context: I'm looking for the third word in a string and there can be as many spaces as possible between the words.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *tokenizeString(char *userCommand)
{
  char *tokenizedString;
  int counterForToken;
  tokenizedString = strtok(userCommand, " ");
  for(counterForToken = 0; counterForToken != 3; counterForToken++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", tokenizedString);
    tokenizedString = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(tokenizedString == NULL)
    {
        break;
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", tokenizedString);
  return tokenizedString; 
}

int main(void)
{
  char userCommand[255] = {0};
  fgets(userCommand, sizeof(userCommand), stdin);
  tokenizeString(userCommand);
}
```

Comment: Suspect your problem lies with `userCommand` prior to calling `tokenizeString`.

Comment: I call my function with `tokenizeString(userCommand);`

Comment: what you have passed in `userCommand` ?

Comment: @StoryTeller I get `UserCommand`  like so: 

`char userCommand[255];
 fgets(userCommand, sizeof(userCommand), stdin);`

Comment: @MaximilianWolf As StoryTeller said above, please post a [mcve]

Comment: @StoryTeller I now added all functions `UserCommand` passes through

Comment: Downvote and close vote for apparent inability to understand what a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example is https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A more to the point MCVE would look like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3a51987ebfb9bca - You can copy this example into your post. The idea is to present just enough to reproduce your problem reliably, without needing your entire program.

Comment: @barny I'm sorry, I first thought it would be enough to only include the function where I think the error occurs. I then added the rest because as I understood from MCVE I should include all steps which might be causing the error.

Comment: @StoryTeller  Ahhhhh I get it now. Sorry for the troubles. I completely misunderstood the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the first printf works but after that I get a Seg Fault. So `tokenizedString = strtok(NULL, " ");` must be causing the issue, right?

No, that is very poor correlation. The issue is in fact in the second call to `printf`. You can pass it `tokenizedString` when `tokenizedString == NULL`. The format specified `%s` is specified to expect a *valid pointer* to the first character of a zero terminated array of characters. Passing it `NULL` is illegal and leads to undefined behavior (causing a crash for instance). The fix is simple: check for a null pointer value. And the same applies to the first iteration of the loop, of course

```
char *tokenizeString(char *userCommand)
{
  char *tokenizedString;
  int counterForToken;
  tokenizedString = strtok(userCommand, " ");
  for(counterForToken = 0; counterForToken != 3 && tokenizedString != NULL; counterForToken++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", tokenizedString);
    tokenizedString = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  if(tokenizedString != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", tokenizedString);
  return tokenizedString; 
}
```

Comment: Jesus I'm an idiot. Thanks for your help with asking the question and providing the answer. As you can probably tell, I have next to no experience with programming.

Comment: @MaximilianWolf - NP. Nobody is born with it. And asking such questions is *hard*. That's why experienced users should strive to help new users. Keep at it and don't let those issues make you disheartened. With experience, this becomes easier.

Comment: Also the third word was what OP wanted. That's the token number 2, not 3. Now the second printf outputs fourth word.

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen - True. But I consider fixing the bug in the implementation's logic secondary to fixing the misuse of the standard library. Now the OP has code without crashes, they can continue on their journey and finish their program.